# Marcar texto em PDF com C#

Tags: c#, pdf

tenho uma aplicação onde serão pesquisados alguns nomes em um determinado arquivo PDF. 
Quando encontrar o nome devo marcar com um "marca texto" as palavras encontradas.
Alguém conhece alguma biblioteca que faça isso?

Estou tentando encontrar em todos os lugares do mundo e nada.

Comment: Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando para achar as palavras? Assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração.

Comment: O que você está usando para gerar o PDF?

Comment: Na verdade estou usando um PDF que já existe e David ainda não tenho o fonte de pesquisa... queria ver se consigo uma biblioteca que vá funcionar bem pros dois.